# phpMyAdmin in Xampp not working

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm getting below error when I type in localhost/phpMyAdmin after starting apache and mysql server in Xampp in Windows 7 environment.

Is there a way I can fix this issue?

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpMyAdmin was not found on this server.
```

Comment: any one can help http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ was not showing anything https://ibb.co/rM52tqk

Comment: if the port `80` is in use when you install xampp then  you will define another port so you can run the apache service in xampp, try to use `localhost:'your defined port'` which will get you the base page of apache, from there you can select phpmyadmin from the menu and go from there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use lowercase: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Apache is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 21):

**404** is the code for **page not found**

If you get this while running both `mysql` and `apache` It means the Url is not correct:

1. Check the alias like in [@kamil's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473476/phpmyadmin-in-xampp-not-working#comment17846132_9473697)
2. If alias is correct then you need to specify the port.

**`http://localhost/phpmyadmin`** is the url if your port is set to default `80`.

In my case I already had a service listennig on that port so I had to change it.

The fix is to add the port if it is a custom one:

**`http://localhost:<port>/phpmyadmin`**

To find out which port you have look inside of `httpd.conf`.

here is a screenshot for xampp:

[image]
To quickly find it, search for `listen`:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

First of all go to apache config.

Now go to select Apache `“httpd.conf”` so now you can see that a notepad file will be opened”.

Find the word `“Listen”` using ctrl + F button or go to Edit then select find.
Replace `“Listen 80”` to `“Listen 8080“`.

Again find another “Listen” now change `“ServerName localhost:80”` to `“ServerName localhost:8080”` and then save it.

“We are almost done to fix localhost/phpmyadmin”
Step 6: Again go to config and select “Apache (httpd-sss.conf)“.

Step 7 is to Find “Listen 443” and change it to “Listen 4433“

Step 8: Find “” and replace this with “” and again save it.

Step 9: Go to config and select “service & ports settings” and change the `port to 8080 and 4433` and save it.

Step 10: Restart, the `localhost/phpmyadmin` is solved.

Thank you, also share this !

Comment: Works like a clarm

Comment: @bijaylimbu is that working fine right?

Answer (score 2):

I just finished installing xampp 1.8.2 on WinXP XP2 machine and got same error show up on my Firefox 24.0 browser:

> xampp Not Found  The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this
>   server.

I solved this problem by changing the proxy of my firefox browser, go to menu tools-Option
find tab Network, click button settings. Fill the text box below No Proxy for with localhost.

In my case then it looklike:

```
192.168.1.0/24, localhost
```

Then press Ok, then Ok again.

Try now typing localhost/xampp then it should show Welcome to XAMPP for Windows!

Note: to change proxy for other browser may differ, check your browser help about how to change proxy.

Hope this help.

Comment: XAMPP was trying PHPMyAdmin on 80 so I just added the port number, 8080 in my case, to the address. Used: http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 1):

Is port 80 being used by another service or app?

I think you can check by the test in:
xammp> apache>service> test>

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the XAMPP and check the phpmyadmin upon reinstalling

Answer (score 0):

Try I did not access it directly like following url pattern  :
url : **`localhost or localhost/file-folder-of your project name.`**

But i can access file or folder and phpmyadmin using

url : **`localhost:port_num/file-folder-of your project name`**