# I can't seem to view mySQL database through xampp's ADMIN button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, xampp

[After clicking xampp's "ADMIN" command...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GERis.png)

[Xampp with Apache and MySQL successfully running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PNFN.png)

[This image shows a runner being successfully added to the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2et18.png)

[Proof that John Wick was added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pKtv.png)

I'm trying to view my data in MySQL through xammp's ADMIN command, but I can't.
I can successfully add new items to the local database, but I am unable to view it. Any tips or solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748086/phpmyadmin-not-working-on-localhost

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473476/phpmyadmin-in-xampp-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhpMyAdmin not working on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748086/phpmyadmin-not-working-on-localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second picture you see the ports of the applications running on XAMP. Apache uses `8080` so try to go to

http://localhost:8080

Comment: Wow. 
http://localhost:80800/phpmyadmin/

This works perfect! I feel like an idiot.